# React Table : How do I total (sum) values to each of the holeOne thru holeNine and display the sum as a value in out: 41?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying total the values of each of the holes and display the total in `out`:

out: `S{holesSum}`,

returns the Object

```js
export const data = [
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Tiger Woods',
    holeOne: 4,
    holeTwo: 5,
    holeThree: 4,
    holeFour: 5,
    holeFive: 5,
    holeSix: 4,
    holeSeven: 5,
    holeEight: 5,
    holeNine: 4,
    out: // want to sum to values of holeOne thru holeNine

  }
]


import ReactTable from 'react-table';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { data } from './data';

const columns = [
  {
    Header: 'Place',
    accessor: 'eventPosition',
    headerStyle: { whiteSpace: 'unset' },
    style: { whiteSpace: 'unset' },
    maxWidth: 60
  },
  {
    Header: 'Player',
    accessor: 'name',
    headerStyle: { whiteSpace: 'unset' },
    style: { whiteSpace: 'unset' },
    maxWidth: 200
  },
  {
    Header: '1',
    accessor: 'holeOne',
    headerStyle: { whiteSpace: 'unset' },
    style: { whiteSpace: 'unset' },
    maxWidth: 50
  },
  {
    Header: '2',
    accessor: 'holeTwo',
    headerStyle: { whiteSpace: 'unset' },
    style: { whiteSpace: 'unset' },
    maxWidth: 50
  },
  {
    Header: '3',
    accessor: 'holeThree',
    headerStyle: { whiteSpace: 'unset' },
    style: { whiteSpace: 'unset' },
    maxWidth: 50
  },
  {
    Header: '4',
    accessor: 'holeFour',
    headerStyle: { whiteSpace: 'unset' },
    style: { whiteSpace: 'unset' },
    maxWidth: 50
  },
  {
    Header: '5',
    accessor: 'holeFive',
    headerStyle: { whiteSpace: 'unset' },
    style: { whiteSpace: 'unset' },
    maxWidth: 50
  },
  {
    Header: '6',
    accessor: 'holeSix',
    headerStyle: { whiteSpace: 'unset' },
    style: { whiteSpace: 'unset' },
    maxWidth: 50
  },
  {
    Header: '7',
    accessor: 'holeSeven',
    headerStyle: { whiteSpace: 'unset' },
    style: { whiteSpace: 'unset' },
    maxWidth: 50
  },
  {
    Header: '8',
    accessor: 'holeEight',
    headerStyle: { whiteSpace: 'unset' },
    style: { whiteSpace: 'unset' },
    maxWidth: 50
  },
  {
    Header: '9',
    accessor: 'holeNine',
    headerStyle: { whiteSpace: 'unset' },
    style: { whiteSpace: 'unset' },
    maxWidth: 50
  },
  {
    Header: 'Out',
    accessor: 'out',
    headerStyle: { whiteSpace: 'unset' },
    style: { whiteSpace: 'unset' },
    maxWidth: 50
  }
];

export default class ReactTableComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ padding: '50px' }}>
        <ReactTable
          manual
          minRows={0}
          pageSize={1}
          data={data}
          columns={columns}
          pages={0}
          showPagination={true}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


({holeOne}, ... {holeNine}).reduce
```

Comment: I don't understand your question :-). Would you consider re-formulating it? Please consider taking the [tour](/tour)

Comment: Hi @Keith, Check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table#custom-cell-header-and-footer-rendering), you can customize your `Cell`.

```
{
    Header: 'Out',
    accessor: 'out',
    headerStyle: { whiteSpace: 'unset' },
    style: { whiteSpace: 'unset' },
    maxWidth: 50,
    Cell: row => {
      console.log(data);
      let columns_to_sum = ["holeOne","holeTwo" , "holeThree" , "holeFour" , "holeFive" , "holeSix" , "holeSeven" , "holeEight" , "holeNine"];
      let result = 0;
      Object.keys(data[row.index]).map(key =>{
        if(columns_to_sum.includes(key)){
          result += data[row.index][key]
        }
      })
      return result;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-njjiup)

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect example for the reduce function like this:

```
const columns_to_sum = ["holeOne","holeTwo" , "holeThree" , "holeFour" , "holeFive" , "holeSix" , "holeSeven" , "holeEight" , "holeNine"];
{
    Header: 'Out',
    accessor: 'out',
    headerStyle: { whiteSpace: 'unset' },
    style: { whiteSpace: 'unset' },
    maxWidth: 50,
    Cell: row => rowData => columns_to_sum.reduce((sum, hole) => sum + rowData.row[hole] || 0,0)
}
```

Using reduce removes the need for a variable to be updated outside and encapsulates the function nicely. You also do not generate an array like with map, which gets discarded, so this approach is also faster.

Here is the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-k7andg?file=index.js).